# Pivot Table Noob Needing Assistance

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

MYSQL

```
COUNTY  OUTAGE  TIME
BOONE   1   2/17/2014 16:03
BOONE   1   2/17/2014 15:36
BOONE   1   2/17/2014 15:18
BOONE   1   2/17/2014 14:14
BOONE   1   2/17/2014 14:13
BROWN   1   2/17/2014 16:03
BROWN   1   2/17/2014 15:36
BROWN   1   2/17/2014 15:18
BROWN   0   2/17/2014 14:14
BROWN   0   2/17/2014 14:13
BUTLER  2   2/17/2014 16:03
BUTLER  2   2/17/2014 15:36
BUTLER  2   2/17/2014 15:18
BUTLER  3   2/17/2014 14:14
BUTLER  3   2/17/2014 14:13
CAMPBELL    0   2/17/2014 16:03
CAMPBELL    0   2/17/2014 15:36
CAMPBELL    0   2/17/2014 15:18
CAMPBELL    0   2/17/2014 14:14
CAMPBELL    0   2/17/2014 14:13
CLERMONT    1   2/17/2014 16:03
CLERMONT    1   2/17/2014 15:36
CLERMONT    1   2/17/2014 15:18
CLERMONT    0   2/17/2014 14:14
CLERMONT    0   2/17/2014 14:13
```

How Can I get my Data to Look More Like

```
COUNTY TIME_1 TIME_2 TIME_3 TIME_4 TIME_5
BOONE 1 1 1 1 1
BROWN 0 1 1 1 0
BUTLER 2 2 2 3 3
```

There will always be five distinct repeating times for each county. I am just at a loss here.

Comment: I mean the data is right there in front of me, and its driving me crazy.

Comment: its because you have bad structure in your table , you didnt create a column called id , which will be autoincrement . or you didnt create column which stores numbers 1 , 2 ,3,4,5 . or there is many options . you just store and then try to break your head on how to manage them .

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
 SELECT COUNTY, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(OUTAGE ORDER BY `TIME` DESC SEPARATOR ' ') AS outstr
   FROM tbl
  GROUP BY COUNTY
```

Here's a fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a13c/1/0 This will give you your five integer values concatenated into a single field. It will order them according to the time columns, latest first. It's not exactly what you specified but it could do the job for you.

If you needed the five columns you could wrap up that query like this.

```
 SELECT COUNTY,
        SUBSTR(outstr, 1, 1) as TIME_1,
        SUBSTR(outstr, 3, 1) as TIME_2,
        SUBSTR(outstr, 5, 1) as TIME_3,
        SUBSTR(outstr, 7, 1) as TIME_4,
        SUBSTR(outstr, 9, 1) as TIME_5
   FROM (
         SELECT COUNTY, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(OUTAGE ORDER BY `TIME` DESC SEPARATOR ' ') AS outstr
           FROM tbl
          GROUP BY COUNTY
        ) AS a
```

Here's a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a13c/5/0  This is a little disgusting. But conventional pivot techniques are made difficult by the lack of unambiguous tags on the rows that you want to pivot up into columns.int

Comment: Not pretty, but prettier than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to order by most recent occurrences; you need to self-join and use the `LIMIT` operator to select the date that you want:

```
select 
  c.county, 
  t1.outage as outage_1, t1.time as time_1, 
  t2.outage as outage_2, t2.time as time_2, 
  t4.outage as outage_3, t3.time as time_3, 
  t4.outage as outage_4, t4.time as time_4, 
  t5.outage as outage_5, t5.time as time_5
from counties c
join (
  select *
  from counties 
  order by time desc 
  limit 0,1
) t1 on t1.county = c.county
join (
  select *
  from counties 
  order by time desc 
  limit 1,1
) t2 on t1.county = c.county
join (
  select *
  from counties 
  order by time desc 
  limit 2,1
) t3 on t1.county = c.county
join (
  select *
  from counties 
  order by time desc 
  limit 3,1
) t4 on t1.county = c.county
join (
  select *
  from counties 
  order by time desc 
  limit 4,1
) t5 on t1.county = c.county
```

Caveat: As with many pivots, this will not be performant. Don't use this for real time queries, only to compile report data.